# column deleted, now want to add constraint back

Tags: sql, postgresql

I deleted a column in a table, using `ALTER TABLE`. I didn't realize that there was a constraint attached to it. Now the constraint also got deleted. How do I add the constraint back? I don't know the exact wording of that constraint. Also, the table was empty, so in that moment I thought the column was never going to be populated and removed it.

Here is the table CREATE query in pgadmin3:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_grade
(
  id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  graded_to uuid,
  grade character varying(10),
  graded_by uuid,
  grade_date timestamp with time zone,
  grade_month timestamp with time zone,
  CONSTRAINT employee_grade_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT employee_grade_by_fk FOREIGN KEY (graded_by)
      REFERENCES employee (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT employee_grade_to_fk FOREIGN KEY (graded_to)
      REFERENCES employee (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I don't know what the constraint was, but I do know that it involved the `graded_by` and `graded_to` foreign keys, and the `grade_month` column. It was also unique.
It probably meant that in that month, `graded_by` graded `graded_to`, and there should not be two gradings in the same month for the same two employees.

Also, if it helps, the corresponding Java entity does not have a corresponding `gradeMonth` column.

Comment: In the future, make a backup with `pg_dump` and run dangerous commands inside a transaction.

Comment: @DanielLyons Okay. Thank you.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Fixed, thanks.

Comment: If you really dropped the column, the you can't get it back. That's one of the reasons why any structural change to a database schema **has** to be done through properly managed migration scripts and those scripts need to be stored in a version control system. Tools like Liquibase help you with that. But for now your only hope is to get this from the backup.

Comment: The table was empty; I just want the constraint back.

Comment: As I said: you can't, unless you have the DDL scripts that _created_ the constraint somewhere

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Will this work? `CONSTRAINT employee_grade_fk UNIQUE (graded_to, graded_by, grade_month)`

Comment: @cst1992: It will do _something_, but whether that _something_ is what you want is a question that no one but you can answer. Note that a `UNIQUE` constraint creates an index, and if any queries rely on that index, then the ordering of fields within the constraint is important.

Comment: @NickBarnes: I have indicated in the question what I want the constraint to do. What do I do with the index and where is it created?

Comment: @cst1992: Ok, you didn't sound too certain on the details. Yes, that constraint will ensure that the combination of those three columns is unique. You can read about indexing [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer indeed was a simple UNIQUE constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT grade_month_uniq UNIQUE (graded_to, graded_by, grade_month)
```

I used this and it works fine for the intended purpose.

Thanks @NickBarnes.